# How to check if the string contains only two words

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make an if statement like this:

```
if(playerMessage == specificallyOnlyTwoWords) {
  // do something
}
```

This means, when for example, "playerMessage" has a value of "Fruit Ninja" it'll will do the code in the if statement, but if the value of the variable is "Great Fruit Ninja" the code in the if statement wont be run.

Two words is a word divided by a blank space or

If possible, if it could pay attention punctuation would be greatly appreciated. "Punctuation" is any character that is not a letter. So for example: `A` is a letter, `;` is punctuation

I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: please add an example of the string and the two words.

Comment: Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: your question is too vague. What qualifies as two words with punctuation? one.two, one. two, one two., .one two, one@#(&$%^@#!(@*&two, etc.

Comment: `Fruit-Ninja` one word or two? `Fruit:Ninja`? It's not clear what you mean by ignore punctuation. Do you want to ignore it in the sense that it doesn't break words or that it does break word.

Comment: @NinaScholz | I've edited the question to show an example.

Comment: Split on `" "`, get length? `playerMessage.split(" ").length === 2`

Comment: @MarkMeyer | Two words is a word divided by a blank space or " "

Comment: Could you go more in-depth on what you mean by "**If possible, if it could ignore punctuation would be greatly appreciated.**"?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn | I've edited the question to go more in-depth.

Comment: Yes... I know the difference between punctuation and non-punctuation :) What do you mean be ignoring them though? What are some examples?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn | If the player sends "Hello, Johnny" then the code won't be ran but if the player sends "Hello Johnny" the code will be ran.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr that doesn't sound like **ignoring** punctuation. That sounds like paying attention to punctuation. You have different results and the only difference in input is the punctuation.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Not to mention, OP accepted an answer that clearly contradicts his latest instruction.

Comment: @TylerRoper | I tested it and it doesn't.

Comment: [I disagree](https://jsfiddle.net/wf0Lb2o9/). The string `"Hello, Johnny"` will be considered two words despite your latest comment saying that it shouldn't be. In fact, Rodrigo's *original* answer behaved as you requested above - it wasn't until you then asked if he could change it that it stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (playerMessage.split(/\W+/).length === 2) {
   // do something
}
```

It will ignore everything that's not a letter.

Comment: "Punctuation" is any character that is not a letter. So for example: A is a letter, ; is punctuation

Comment: Could I just split the characters that aren't a letter and not a space.

Comment: Done, now it matches everything that's not a letter nor space.

Comment: Finally, thank you very much. I thought my question was straightforward but I guess not with the amount of comments I got...

Comment: @Tigerrrrr It's even more unclear now. You yourself said `"Hello, Johnny"` should **not** be considered two words, but then accepted an answer that does exactly that. (No fault of Rodrigo, you seem to have requested this behavior.)

Comment: @TylerRoper | I tested it and it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can split on `non-word characters` by using `\W` then you can test the length of the split string:

```js
let strs = ['Hello, Johnny', 'Hello,Johnny', 'Hello Johnny', 'Hello \n World', 'Hello   World']

strs.forEach(str => console.log(str, str.split(/\W/).length === 2))

console.log('-- Trim Witespace ---')

// Replace extra whitespace
strs.forEach(str => console.log(str, str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').split(/\W/).length === 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way.  Count the number of global matches of white space and return true if there is only one.

```js
var strings = ['two words','one more word', 'a bunch of words']
strings.filter(str => {
 console.log(str.match(/\s/g).length === 1)
})
```